# Why is it only outputting the information for the student in the last loop spot? i.e. The 19th student

Tags: c

I think i stored the memory correctly

```
    student *Class;     // created an array of 19 total students
    Class = (student *)malloc(sizeof(Class)* 19 );
                                            //taking in the information for each student


    Class->first = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)* 19 );
    Class->last = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 19 );
    Class->exam1 = (int)malloc(sizeof(int) * 19 );
    Class->exam2 = (int)malloc(sizeof(int) * 19 );
    Class->exam3 = (int)malloc(sizeof(int) * 19 );
```

In this loop I am only seeing the information for the 19th student if i change "i <20;" to "i < 9;" it will only output information on the 8th student.

```
    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    scanf("%s", Class->first);
    scanf("%s", Class->last);
    scanf("%d", &Class->exam1);
    scanf("%d", &Class->exam2);
    scanf("%d", &Class->exam3);
    Class->mean = (Class->exam1 + Class->exam2 + Class->exam3) / 3;
    } // 

    for (i = 0; i < 20; i++){
    printf("%s   %s   %f \n", Class->first, Class->last, Class->mean);
    }
```

here's the definition for the student struct

```
    typedef struct student_info {
    char  *first;
    char  *last;
    int   exam1;
    int   exam2;
    int   exam3;
    float mean;
    } student;
```

Comment: You are only accessing the first entry of the array in all parts of the code shown. To access other entries do `Class[i].first`, etc

Comment: You need to show the definition of the `student` struct. It's not clear whether you're trying to make an array of `struct` or a `struct` of arrays. See [mcve].

Comment: exactly! you cannot just expect everyone to think like you and do and understand what you did, unless you tell us properly

Comment: Side note: you are only allocating storage for 19 elements in each array, but your `i` loops iterate over 20 elements.  If you start indexing these arrays, you will index past the end of the array, and any read or write to data at that location will have undefined behavior.

Comment: What is with all the instances of `19` here? This is concerning. Tip: `#define` any constant values you have and use those macro definitions, don't copy-paste numbers like `19` all over the place.

Comment: Note an array of size 19 has indexes 0..18, so your loop should be `< 19`. Your use of `< 20` in one place and `<= 19` in another is really inconsistent and distracting. Pick one style and stick to it.

Comment: Sorry guys this is my first time using this website. I appreciate the feedback and I'll get to it.

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) and `sizeof(char)` is defined as `1` -- so that is superfluous.

Comment: I have answered the question you asked here. Would you like to ask a new separate question on how to make something in which multiple sets of data for studenty can be stored? For that make a [mre] of the same code and ask a differently focused question. Then another question can be on how to scan into it. Then another questin could be on how to change it to make it flexibly sized with the help of malloc. Seperate, clear, focused questions....

Answer (score 1):

Apart from all the side issues mentioned in the comments...

In both your loops, the one with `scanf()` and the one with `printf()`, the looping variable `i` is never used.
So you scan all information into the same place and you print 20 (9) times from the same place.
The "place" you use is very questionable and your way of creating it implies that you intend it to be similar to an array. But without using `i` (or doing something like iterating through a linked list), you cannot expect to get anything but the same values serveral times.

So that is why you only get output of the last student.

The solution is too complex to fix it here, at least without a MRE and in a way that you can follow.
Keywords for the involved topics are "arrays", "data types", "pointers", "array of structs", "struct of arrays", "loops".

Comment: Your edit to the question makes things even weirder, but does not really change anything relevantly. I assumed pointers where I now see ints. But at least your (unneccessary) casts make a little more sense now.